# Entity framework core - user specified primary key value not saving

Tags: entity-framework-core, primary-key

I am using this code to save a student to student table. ID is the primary key in the table.

```
_context.Add(student);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

A student object with these values works and the record is added with the next available ID in the table.

```
Firstname: Firstname
Lastname: Lastname
Date: {03/02/2019 23:59:00}
ID: 0
```

The below student object fails and causes a "DbUpdateException" Exception.

```
Firstname: Firstname
Lastname: Lastname
Date: {03/02/2019 23:59:00}
ID: 66 (or any other int value that isn't already used in the table)
```

Is it not possible to specify a value for a Primary Key in EF?  Or is there a particular way of specifying a user value?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using auto-generated primary key?

Comment: Is auto-generated the default option? The context class or the model has no mention of it.

Comment: @SANM2009 Yes, it is by [convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties#conventions)